# Validations in VBA access

Tags: vba, ms-access

In a Textbox it will carry the value of a percentage with decimals but I only want to be able to capture a single decimal point and only 2 decimals without rounding, I have already looked for a thousand ways and I can't find how

currently I only lied the validation that I only accept numbers in the ON KEY PRESS event

first of all, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If figured out a solution using the KeyPress event. As you can see it is quite difficult to account for all possible circumstances. For instance the user could have moved the cursor to a position before the decimal point or he/she could have selected text or try to enter a decimal point in the middle of a number which would result in more decimal than allowed.

In this example I named my TextBox `Number`:

```vb
Private Sub Number_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Dim s As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    
    If InStr(Number.Text, ".") > 0 And KeyAscii = Asc(".") Then
        ' Do not allow a second decimal point
        KeyAscii = 0
    ElseIf KeyAscii >= Asc("0") And KeyAscii <= Asc("9") Then
        s = Number.Text & Chr$(KeyAscii)
        pos = InStr(s, ".")
        ' Do not allow more than 2 decimal but allow input if before decimal point.
        If pos > 0 And Len(s) - pos - Number.SelLength > 2 And Number.SelStart >= pos Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    ElseIf KeyAscii <> Asc(".") And KeyAscii <> 8 Then ' 8 = Backspace
        ' Do not allow other characters to be entered
        KeyAscii = 0
    ElseIf KeyAscii = Asc(".") And Number.SelStart < Len(Number.Text) - Number.SelLength - 2 Then
        ' Do not allow entering a decimal point if this results in more than 2 decimals
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage Regular Expressions for this task:

```
Option Explicit

Private Reg As RegExp
Private EnteredText As String

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set Reg = New RegExp
   Reg.Pattern = "^(\d+(\.\d{0,2})?|\.?\d{1,2})$"
   Reg.Global = True
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   'allow backspace
   If KeyAscii = 8 Then Exit Sub
   
   'build the string
   EnteredText = Mid(Text1.Text, 1, Text1.SelStart) & Chr(KeyAscii) & Mid(Text1.Text, Text1.SelStart + 1)
   
   'if not a valid string cancel the keystroke
   If Not Reg.Test(EnteredText) Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The no-code method is to set an *InputMask*:

```
##0.##
```

It will also catch a paste.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to work only for text and datetime types.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for the issue of only being able to insert a decimal point.

```vb
Private Sub textbox_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    'If InStr("0123456789.", Chr(KeyAscii)) = 0 And KeyAscii <> 8 Then KeyAscii = 0
       Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, _
        vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
            If KeyAscii = 46 Then If InStr(1, textbox.Text, ".") Then KeyAscii = 0
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
    
End Sub
```